# How the computer could be used by two users at the same time

Tags: windows, terminal, cursor, multiseat

Running windows 7 64, Is there any application that allows me to connect an additional keeyboard and mice and monitor, so that this can be used by other user at the samee time while I use the main computer,
There is an application called cpnmouse but it doesnt work on win7, betwin crashes before win7 start up, teamplayer is too expensive

Has anyone figured out this functionality maybe with virtual machinees or something, i've tried team player in a virtual machine but it crashes
I have 3 monitors one of theem is a Tv, i would like that my girlfried uses it as a terminal without me loosing the focus cause she uses the mice
There is a linux software called userful, but it's linux and doesnt work for me, and windows multipoint server needs a clean installation and also that's not a valid choice

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc/768747#768747

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can two users simultaneously share one pc](https://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer, as far as I'm aware, is "No".

Windows 7 (Vista, XP, et. al.) is a "Workstation" OS, meaning it is only intended to serve one console at a time.  Even with Remote Desktop, the workstation's local display gets locked while the remote user takes control.

Your suggestion of virtualization is an intersting one, however it will not likely be cost-effective.  First, you would have to have an additional OS license for the VM.  Second, you would have to have an additional computer from which to remotely connect to the VM.  Third, the remote user still would not be directly interfacing with the Host computer, thereby defeating the purpose of this exercise.  At this point, the remote user may as well just use their own computer for their own purposes.

If you want multiple users to have simultaneous access to one Windows system, the only solution is to buy a Server OS.  Again however, this would still require the remote user(s) to have their own workstations from which they can connect to the Server.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may just rather let everyone use their own computer (and host a file share on the "server" system) instead of divvying up resources on one system that wasn't designed for it.

Comment: but with Teamplayer is possible, thee probleem it's too expensive.The only one i need is that the tv be used to access internet with its own keyboard and mouse without mee loosing the hability to use them

Comment: @Husker - I'm not sure you understand what it is you're asking for here.  Teamplayer still requires a separate computer, and will still use the same session (in Win7, there is only one) on the computer - thereby hijacking keyboard and mouse control from any other users.