# dual monitor PC into dual station PC

Tags: multiple-monitors, user-accounts, multiple-instances

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can two users simultaneously share one pc](https://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc)

I have a Intel Core i3 laptop, a set of extra monitor, mouse and keyboard, and what I want is to be able to support two independent users, one directly on laptop and one using the extra monitor, mouse and keyboard. I guess this is possible, But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible with normal Windows versions (Terminal Server would be something else) on a direct way.

It may be possible by using a virtual machine with dedicated mouse and keyboard, directly passed through to it. Of course, in that case you need enough computing power and a second operating system on the VM.

The X Windows System used by unix-based operating systems may support this, but I am not familiar with unix-based OS.