# Can i play 2 instances of a game at the same time?

Tags: multiple-monitors, multi-boot, gaming, multiple-instances, multiple-users

I have a friend who comes to my place often but i only have 1 pc so i was wondering if it was possible to play 2 games at once on two separate screens. I have 24 gb of ram, a 3.5-3.9 ghz quad core cpu and a gtx 770 OC video card so i don't think power wont be a issue. But is it possible to have a 2 player setup on a single computer running separate instances of a game?

Comment: How would your friend control the game?

Comment: Running multiple instances might not be enough. You might need a solution to split inputs - even if you have two pairs of mouse and keyboard, their inputs will be mixed up without the solution. If it's the case, this might help you. http://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on the game and you might be able to hack it to do that. The reason is that may have been written to read/write places that are common - say like your profile then it might be difficult to get it to run from an alternative location and not read/write to the common locations.

However if the game is not gfx intensive then you could run a virtual machine for the second instance. For instance VirtualBox from Oracle is free.