# How to share only one application without virtualization?

Tags: windows-10, sharing

How to share only one application with a remote partner without the guest taking control of the hosting machine? I have a relatively big program running on Windows 10 only and another MAC user needs access, but I would like to run this program in background and use the PC while the remote user does its work.

My understanding of Application Virtualization options like Cameyo is that it requires program installation at some stage, an option I do not have.

Is there any other solution?

Thanks.

Comment: The requirements of carrying on your work while someone else is using your PC as well as installing no other software makes this pretty much impossible without a VM. https://superuser.com/questions/106842/can-two-users-simultaneously-share-one-pc

Comment: Yes, VM seems the way to go. No alternative to install the program again.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider installing the program on a Windows *server* so that both of you can remote desktop in to access it when you need it. There are cloud providers (AWS EC2, Microsoft Azure) that make setting this up easy. This also gives the benefit of the program being accessible to your partner, even if you shut down your computer.