# Run two users on the same computer (windows 7)

Tags: windows, user

I'd like to use one computer for two people preferably on windows 7, without having to use another computer to connect to a virtual machine.

Comment: This is called a Multiseat configuration. I have tried to do it before, but it is really very complicated. You might want to take a look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/29879/setting-up-a-multiseat-configuration

Comment: or you might try this if you are willing to use linux http://www.userful.com/products/downloads/free-2-user

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a previous comment that referred to [an outdated post](https://superuser.com/questions/29879/setting-up-a-multiseat-configuration) I figured out that this was called "mutliseating" and ran a quick google search:
http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1672694/multi-seat-gaming-howto.html